# Python "requests" not sending whole response data

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a small program that returns the opening/closing times of certain locations through utilizing the 'bs4' and 'requests' library (I'm webscraping TripAdvisor for this purpose). However, whenever I request a certain HTML, it does not return the whole file.

For example, when I webscrape the The Metropolitan Museum of Art (https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g60763-d105125-Reviews-The_Metropolitan_Museum_of_Art-New_York_City_New_York.html), I want to receive the data "Hours Today: 10:00 AM - 9:00 PM" that's under the "Contents" section.

[image]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get("https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g60763-d105125-Reviews-The_Metropolitan_Museum_of_Art-New_York_City_New_York.html").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

print(soup.prettify())
```

But when I use this line

```
soup.find("div", class_="attractions-attraction-detail-about-card-AboutSection__sectionWrapper--3PMQg")
```

Nothing returns back. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Lots of sites are dynamic. Compare what requests is returning to what your browser *initially* receives, or to the output of `curl`.

Comment: Hi ericchoirr38 I can't find `"Hours Today: 10:00 AM - 9:00 PM" that's under the "Contents" section.` Can you add an image ...

Comment: @Yatin Sure. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xs-vjvhoxGyDBM0ZGAppilGkj0FKsb8q/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ericchoirr38 I require access to see this image..

Comment: @ericchoirr38 watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSH77vnOGqU